# Cross-cluster communication between Private GKE Clusters fails (Pod to Control Plane)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We've got 2 Private GKE clusters on the same GCP project. They're both located in the same VPC.

Cluster A is a cluster running Jenkins with agents as ephemeral pods.
Cluster B is where our microservices are deployed.

Cluster A needs to reach Cluster B.

When trying to deploy with Helm, we're getting:

> Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get
> "https://192.168.221.18/version": dial tcp 192.168.221.18:443: i/o
> timeout

**192.168.221.18** is the private Control Plane endpoint of Cluster B.

What I tried so far:

Since the clusters are on the same VPC network, I checked the routes for Cluster A subnet:

Saw that there's a subnet peering for 192.168.221.16/28:

I added the cluster A node IP address (we have only one node)to the firewall that allows traffic on 443 to the Cluster B control plane:

I still get the same error message for timeout from the Jenkins agent.
So what I'm asking is it even possible to reach Cluster B's control plane from a Pod in cluster A?

Thank you.

Comment: Are both clusters in the same region?

Comment: Yes, this issue is now solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is now solved. If someone ever encounters this issue with an **internal** control plane endpoint:

Since the clusters are on the same VPC and region, the secondary Pod range is used when trying to reach Cluster B's control plane. If your Secondary Pod IP range doesn't fall into a public range, you can add it to the control plane's master authorized addresses and that should do it.

If that's not the case, you'll have to use ip-masq-agent. Install it and create a configMap like this:

```
nonMasqueradeCIDRs:
  - 192.168.114.0/24
  - 172.38.0.0/21 
masqLinkLocal: false
resyncInterval: 60s
```

Where 192.168.114.0/24 is Cluster A's subnet range and 172.38.0.0/21 is the secondary Pod IP range. This should tell the ip-masq-agent that NAT isn't required for those ranges. This now means that the Node IP address is the one reaching the control plane and not the Secondary Pod IP Range.

Comment: what if the clusters are in different projects, VPCs?